# Animation Nodes available for Blender 3.3?

Tags: animation

Can anyone let me know if "Animation nodes" plugin still available for Blender 3.3

Comment: Why don't you check the official homepage? https://animation-nodes.com/#download

Comment: yes it is. it even runs under 3.5 alpha

Comment: Thank you Chris